# Is it possible to win the first fight in Grubbins on Ice?

Tags: costume-quest

After completing Costume Quest's main story line, I just lost the very first fight of the Grubbins on Ice expansion. The enemies do an insane amount of damage, and it doesn't look like you can pick your costumes and Battle Stamps either.

However, after having been defeated, I got a little cutscene of my party being shoved off a cliff, and the game continued, so clearly the game expected me to lose. I didn't lose by a lot, though.

So, is it possible to win this first fight, and what happens if you do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I lost this battle like you did, and I believe it's intentional that you lose.  The story carries on from there.  However, some people have [reported winning it](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/604987-costume-quest/57470955), and the game just carries on the same way as before.

The reward for winning this battle is 7500 xp.

Answer (score 7):

If you want first-hand experience, I finished it (barely). As the others have said, you get EXP for finishing the fight and still get pushed off the cliff. An NPC later mentions something about you losing, so they're definitely working on most people losing that fight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can win. I was playing with my maxed out characters from the main game and they beat me too as I recall. They are simply quite overpowered compared to your current level.

Answer (score -3):

A simple Google search will tell you that several other people have won the first battle. You get a hefty XP bonus but that's all, the game continues the same as if you lost.

Comment: We prefer firsthand experience or at least *something* more verifiable than the random pages a Google search brings up (i.e. links are good...pictures are better...).

Comment: Apparently, the response to 'Let me Google that for you' is 'Let me downvote that for you'.

Comment: @SteveV. If this answer did not have that pre-amble, it probably would not have attracted all these downvotes, true. Apparently it's a somewhat touchy issue right at this moment. I upvoted it because I *was* wondering why I was only level 24 when I finished the game, having fought everything. Now I know where that missing XP is.